# Srcipt vbs, moveFolder return Permission denied

Tags: windows, vbscript

```
Option Explicit
dim fso
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If fso.FolderExists("C:\Users\michal\Desktop\mv_files_backup") then
fso.MoveFolder "C:\Users\michal.glowacki\Desktop\mv_files_backup\*.*", "\\192.168.10.245\backup\servers\backup_server"
Else
wscript.echo "doesn't exist"
End If
```

When I try run this script I have error:

> Permission denied 800A0046

but when I change `MoveFolder` to `CopyFolder` script works correctly. Why I can't use function `MoveFolder` ?

Comment: drop the `*.*` from the `MoveFolder` call.  It means to refer to the files within the folder, which is fine for a `CopyFolder` but not for a `MoveFolder`, which expects a folder path only.

Comment: @Dave I remove `*.*`, but still I have this same error.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/movefolder-method):

> If source contains wildcards or **destination ends with a path separator
>   ( \ ), it is assumed that destination specifies an existing folder in
>   which to move the matching files. Otherwise, destination is assumed to
>   be the name of a destination folder to create**. In either case, three
>   things can happen when an individual folder is moved:
>
> If destination does not exist, the folder gets moved. This is the
>   usual case.
>
> If destination is an existing file, an error occurs.
>
> **If destination is a directory, an error occurs**.
>
> An error also occurs if a wildcard character that is used in source
>   doesn't match any folders. The MoveFolder method stops on the first
>   error it encounters. No attempt is made to roll back any changes made
>   before the error occurs.

I've marked **in bold** the parts that explain your problem.  Because your destination doesn't end with a trailing backslash, your script is attempting to create the folder, and failing.  Try it with a `\` added to the end of the destination and report back if it still doesn't work.

Try this:

```
fso.MoveFolder "C:\Users\michal.glowacki\Desktop\mv_files_backup", "\\192.168.10.245\backup\servers\backup_server\"
```

Comment: I tried to do that by adding a mark "\" to the end of the destination, but script return strill this same error, I change code and now I use function `CopyFolder` and `DeleteFolder` after copying all folders.